# At what scenario will a LCD monitor that used mercury inside their lamp be harmful

Tags: safety, toxicity

Small amount of mercury and/or mercury vapors is harmful to human as it can cause damage to vital organs such as brain, heart and so on.

However, there are many electronic devices such as LCD monitor that used lamp that contain mercury for operation.

So, in what scenario will a LCD monitor that used lamp that contain mercury harmful?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluorescent_lamps_and_health

Comment: Most modern fluorescent lamps use little mercury and have amalgam, rather than free mercury, in the lamp (the mercury vaporizes when the amalgam is heated). The harm is from *many* lamps being added to landfills, but is probably less significant than mercury freed by burning coal (about 500 tonnes in 2010).

Comment: I might, somewhat tongue in cheek, suggest that the glass shards from breaking the lamp open might be more of a health hazard than the small quantity of mercury...